# Is there a way to dynamically create django models(classes)?

Tags: python, django, oop, design-patterns

I have been assigned a challenging task recently, we are designing a website for our customers, and my boss wanted me to create flexible model-creation functions: which means he doesn't want us to "hard code" the models, he told us not to manually define django models but to create them at system runtime.
For example, we have no models related to our business process at first, admin users can define a form's format on our front pages which will be processed by general users later. Then our backend receives the request from front-end and create the form model with fields provided. I found I can create a class by type() function like type(class_name, (models.Model,), attrs), and I did get new class via this function.
But I was wondering how to persist this class in our system? Like saving this new class into my models.py and making migration so that our DB has it as well
To simplify this, I have pseudo code lies below:

```
form_class_attrs = {
    'test_val': models.FloatField(),
    'test_name': models.CharField(),
    '__module__': __name__,
    }

def test(request):
    form_list = ['a', 'b']
    for form in form_list:
        form_class_name = "form_%s" % form
        attrs = form_class_attrs.copy()
        form_class = type(form_class_name, (models.Model,), attrs)
```

Here I create two classes in the for loop, so how do I persist each form_class in the for loop and make migrations correspondingly?

Comment: Please post what you have tried so that people can help understand and help you acheive what ypu want.

Comment: You may want to dig into the source at https://github.com/rvinzent/django-dynamic-models

Comment: @AMG Thanks! I'm looking into this, which seems like what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Your dynamically created classes should, after `test`is called, be equivalent to the equivalent declarative Model - that is correct.

In order for django to *use* these models, they have to be passed along to were they will be used. So, you created a `form_class` variable that is local to the `test` factory function: you have to return this value to outside the function, and keep a process-wide reference to each class created so that Django can use it. (It won't work calling the function and re-creating the model each time you need it, as Django would create a new model that would conflict with the previous one, at least in the ORM-resources needed).

Apart from that, you should not create the field instances just once, for all classes, and try just to call `form_class_attrs.copy`on them: that would try to reuse the same fields in different classes. Along that line, you would have to use `deepcopy`- but there is a *huge* chance that won't work either, due to internal identifiers that are generated when fields are created. You have to re-create the field instances (i.e. make the actual call to `.CharField()` for each dynamic class. The easiest way (not the best) to do that is just move the attr_fields declaration to inside your for-loop.

Calling the factory function once, and returning all models in a list or dictionary would suffice for model usage - but not for migration purposes (including class creation) - the migration mechanisms in Django likely depend on importing all modules and them checking for the existing models: I am not sure of this, but I think it depends on finding the models in a module namespace, not just "created". So, they have to be added to the module namespace upon importing - even if they are not used. In Python this can be done by updating the dictionary returned by the `globals()` call.

All in all, this should work for you:

```
def test():
    form_list = ['a', 'b']
    forms = {}
    for form in form_list:
        attrs = {
            'test_val': models.FloatField(),
            'test_name': models.CharField(),
            '__module__': __name__,
        }
        form_class_name = f"form_{form}" 
        form_class = type(form_class_name, (models.Model,), attrs)
        forms[form_class_name] = form_class

all_forms = test()
globals().update(all_forms)
```